# Python - PHP Shell Exec

Tags: php, python

If I run the following via the command line I have no issues:

```
python /home/forge/default/public/test.py http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/195/XM1014-GRASSLAND-WELL-WORN
```

However if I execute this in php:

```
shell_exec('python /home/forge/default/public/test.py http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/195/XM1014-GRASSLAND-WELL-WORN');
```

It doesn't run correctly?

Comment: Wat doesn't run correctly? See any errors?

Comment: It seems ExecJS can't select NodsJS as the JS runtime when ran via php, however has no issues when ran manually, any ideas?

Comment: First calling a python script from within a php script does not make a lot of sense.

Second, have you actually ran the code in a test environment and gotten an error? 

The path of knowledge is littered with attempts from doing not questions of pondering.